# Pass a Queue to handle_read function async tcp server

Tags: python, event-handling, python-multiprocessing, tcpserver, asyncore

I'm using a multiprocess to make 2 tasks. A process 1 is a async tcp server which receives commands and have to pass these commands to process 2 (is a while true loop).

How i'm using multiprocessing, the process don't share global variables, so i have to use a queue. But, a proccess 1 is a simple asynctcp server. I don't know how to pass the queue object to handle_read fuction.

Anyone have an idea? Thanks a lot!

The code i'm trying:

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
#import dos módulos necessarios

import time
import collections
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from threading import Timer
import os
import sys
from smbus import SMBus
from struct import pack, unpack
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import asyncore
import socket


bstatus = 0
lastdata = {}

#bytechecksum para confirmação
chksum = 15


#funções auxiliares

def millis():
    dt = datetime.now()-start_time
    ms = (dt.days*24*60*60 + dt.seconds)*1000+dt.microseconds / 1000.0  
    return ms

def getbit(data,index):
    return(data & (1<<index)!=0)

def parseData(data):
    mydata = {}

    if data[8] == 27:
        mydata['Temp1'] = data[0]
        mydata['Temp2'] = data[1]
        mydata['Temp3'] = data[2]
        mydata['Temp4'] = data[3]
        mydata['HotFlow'] = data[4]
        mydata['ColdFlow'] = data[5]
        mydata['PumpSpeed'] = data[6]
        mydata['PumpStatus'] = getbit(data[7],0)
        mydata['HeaterStatus'] = getbit(data[7],1)
        mydata['ArduinoMode'] = getbit(data[7],2)
        mydata['TimeStamp'] = timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]

        #pegar o modo do arduino
        arduino_mode = mydata['ArduinoMode']      
        parseStatus = True
    else:
        parseStatus = False

    return parseStatus, mydata


#classes para implmmentar o servidor assincrono

class dataHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    #this function doesn't working
    def __init__(self,sock,queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.sock = sock

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.sock.recv(50)

        '''interpretar os comandos:
        operação: Ligar/Desligar Bomba, Ligar/Desligar Aquecedor, Alterar velocidade da bomba
        Modo: trocar de modo automático para remoto
        Armazenamento: ativar ou desativar o armazenamento de dados para o trend
        '''

        if(data == b'7'):
            operation_mode = 1
            queue.put(data)
            print(data)

        elif(data == b'8'):
            operation_mode = 0
            queue.put(data)
            print(data)          

        try:
            bytescommand = pack('=cb',data,chksum)
            bus.write_block_data(arduinoAddress,ord(data),list(bytescommand))
        except Exception as err:
            print(str(err))
        finally:
            pass
            #print(data)

class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self,host,port,queue):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind((host,port))
        self.listen(1)
        self.queue = queue 

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is None:
            return
        else:
            sock,addr = pair
            handler = dataHandler(sock,self.queue) #doesn't working


#classe para implementar a função principal

def tcpserver(queue):
    server = Server('localhost',8080,queue)
    asyncore.loop()

def mainloop(stime,ftime,queue):
    prevmillis = stime
    prevmillis2 = ftime
    operation_mode = 1
    while True:
        try:
            currentmillis2 = millis()
            if(queue.empty):
                pass
            else:
                print(queue.get())

            if(currentmillis2 - prevmillis2 > readinterval):
                #do some stuff


#programa principal

if __name__=='__main__':


    prevmillis= millis()       #contador para solicitação de dados para o arduino
    prevmillis2 = prevmillis   #contador para envio do banco

    #create Queue
    queue = Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=tcpserver,args=(queue,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=mainloop,args=(prevmillis,prevmillis2,queue,))
    p2.start()

    strstatus = 'Servidor rodando'

    print(strstatus)
```

Comment: What does your program do when it gets to the statement that you have marked as not working?  Is an exception raised?  If so, please post the traceback.

Comment: Doesn't return any errors. But the queue.get() never executes, so queue always is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In `mainloop` you don't test the return value of `queue.empty`, you test the function object itself.  That always evaluates `True`, so it looks like `queue` is always empty.  Change to a function call:

```
def mainloop(stime,ftime,queue):
    prevmillis = stime
    prevmillis2 = ftime
    operation_mode = 1
    while True:
        try:
            currentmillis2 = millis()
            if(queue.empty()):   # Added () 
                pass
            else:
                print(queue.get())

            if(currentmillis2 - prevmillis2 > readinterval):
                #do some stuff
```